# Dispose Derived Class

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class that derives from the `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`. The class will only contain some HTML formatted static text for the email body.

```
public sealed class CustomMessage : MailMessage
{
    public void SendTo(params string[] addresses)
    {
        foreach (var address in addresses)
        {
            SendTo(address);
        }
    }

    public void SendTo(string address)
    {
        To.Add(address);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then I can wrap it in a `using` statement:

```
using (var message = new CustomMessage())
{
     message.SendTo("address1", "address2");
     //...
}
```

The `MailMessage` base class implements `IDisposable`:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
  if (!disposing || this.disposed)
    return;
  this.disposed = true;
  if (this.views != null)
    this.views.Dispose();
  if (this.attachments != null)
    this.attachments.Dispose();
  if (this.bodyView == null)
    return;
  this.bodyView.Dispose();
}
```

Do I still need to override the `Dispose(bool)` method although there's nothing really to dispose in my class?

```
bool disposed = false;

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposed)
     return; 

     if (disposing) 
     {
        // Nothing managed to dispose.
     }

     // Nothing unmanaged to dispose.

     disposed = true;
     base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Comment: No, you only need to override it if you need to do anything special (such as setting a flag or disposing items that were created or are owned by the derived class).

Comment: [This](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/03/30/idisposable-part-2-subclass-from-an-idisposable-class/) is a really good read.

Comment: off-topic comment: those `SendTo` methods doesn't looks like a reason to extending the class ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `CustomMessage` inherits the base `Dispose()` and `Dispose(bool)` methods. It doesn't need to override them unless it has to do some extra disposing on its own.

I just noticed you use System.Net.Mail.MailMessage. Don't. It's obsolete and Microsoft itself warns strongly against using it.

**Alternative to a custom message**

In any case, it's better to write an extension method to add multiple recipients than creating a new message class. You could create something like this in MimeKit, the proposed replacement for SmtpClient :

```
static public void AddRecipients(this MimeMessage message,IEnumerable<string> addresses)
{
    var ads=addresses.Select(ad=>MailboxAddress.Parse(ad));
    message.To.AddRange(ads);
}
```

Or this for SmptClient

```
static public void AddRecipients(this MailMessage message,IEnumerable<string> addresses)
{
    foreach (var address in addresses)
    {
        message.To.Add(address);
    }
}
```

**SmptClient is obsolete**

I just noticed you use System.Net.Mail.MailMessage. Don't. Microsoft itself [warns against using SmptClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=netframework-4.8) in a *very* strongly formatted warning, at the very top of SmptClient's doc page :

> Warning
>
> This API is now obsolete.

In fact, you should be getting a compiler warning already :

> SmtpClient and its network of types are poorly designed, we strongly recommend you use https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit and https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit instead

You should change your code to use MailKit. You may not have to create a custom message in the first place.

The API is similar to SmptClient for simple cases and there's even a cast operation from `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` to MimeKit's own `MimeMessage` to make the transition easier.

The example from [MailKit's Github landing page](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) shows how easy it is to use it

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey Tribbiani", "joey@friends.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Mrs. Chanandler Bong", "chandler@friends.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin'?";

message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") {
    Text = @"Hey Chandler,

I just wanted to let you know that Monica and I were going to go play some paintball, you in?

-- Joey"
};

using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s,c,h,e) => true;

    client.Connect ("smtp.friends.com", 587, false);

    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
    client.Authenticate ("joey", "password");

    client.Send (message);
    client.Disconnect (true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't have anything extra to dispose you don't need to override Dispose.